# Why would an HTTP connection stall after exactly 3 ethernet frames?

Tags: http, networking, ethernet, mtu

I am looking at an application which transmits precisely 4380 bytes over HTTP, including headers, before the connection stalls. 4380 happens to be exactly 3 times the maximum segment size of a 1500-byte Ethernet frame (1500 bytes minus 40 bytes of TCP/IP headers times 3).

The connection appears to remain open; it's just that no data is being received.

Why would it stall after precisely 3 ethernet frames? Where should I start looking for a reason?

Comment: *Every* HTTP connection?

Comment: You will have to be more specific: what client application are we talking about? If it is one of your own, what HTTP and network libraries are you using? In what cases does the connection stall? Is it always when the client application sends 4380 bytes or more? Nevertheless, I highly doubt the Ethernet layer is the problem.

Comment: Well those 3 Ethernet frames are also 3 IP packets. I don't see any reason to concentrate on Ethernet here.

Comment: @jl6, what is the MSS of the TCP connection?  Is there a firewall or packet filter involved?